# Ngrok on Startup

Tags: startup

I have a ngrok account - and I would like to run the program in the terminal automatically when the computer boots up.
How can I create a file that will be executed right away and calls the process, e.g. this one
" ./ngrok start configfile"
Thank you!
Frank

Comment: Hi Frank, welcome to Stack Overflow. As it stands your question is a bit too broad. Try formatting your question in a way so that it is contained to a single issue https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

> Most *Linux distributions* includes scripts in `/etc/init.d` directory, which are started during the boot process (or executed when you shutdown or reboot the system). For instance on *Redhat* or *CentOS Linux*, the `/etc/init.d/httpd` script runs at boot time, and starts *Apache daemons*.

[/etc/init.d - Linux Shell Scripting Tutorial - A Beginner's handbook](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide//etc/init.d)